# Unable to close many buffers by one command in Vim

Tags: vim

I use Vim in Screen. I run the command

```
vim <bigFolder>
```

I am in stuck, since it does not make sense to close each buffer by

```
:q
```

**How can you close all active buffers in Vim,** by one command inside Vim?

Comment: I cannot even use the command Ctrl-D to close screen, since I am in browsing a folder. It does not help to close Vim, since I am in Screen, everything remains from the last session.

Comment: I think you've confused buffers with windows. :q or :quit closes the current window. Use :bd or :bdelete to unload a buffer and delete it from the buffer list. sunaku's answer is the only one to this point that got it right :)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`:qall` or `:qa` will close all windows

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day. My terminal would be useless without your command.

Comment: :qa is what the OP wanted but of course it also quits vim. For gvim this is often undesirable when you want to just completely close everything but not lose your gui window, so it's better to use one of the techniques below to close all buffers without quitting.

Answer (score 81):

The `:bufdo` command lets you execute a command on all buffers.  In this case, you want to run `:bufdo bdelete` to close all open buffers in one go.

Comment: Since bdelete accepts a range, you can also do :1,9999bd where 9999 is just a number high enough to plausibly include any open buffer number.

Answer (score 65):

:%bd(elete)

I think this is what you asking for

Comment: how would you apply this to just one buffer?  `:bd` maybe?

Answer (score 16):

```
:on
```

will close all buffers except the one you are currently editing (the cursor is inside this buffer).

```
:on!
```

will also close modified buffers but these will become hidden buffers.

```
:ls
```

will lists all the buffers with their status (hidden, ...)

Some help:

```
:h only
:h hidden-buffer
:h ls
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! - - I cannot see the difference between the option [!] and without it. All my buffers just get hidden by both commands, even my saved ones. How can you see the difference?

Comment: I took this from the vim help and you're right, I don't see the difference between the two.

Comment: It seems that it is a mistake in the manual. Do you know where is the errata of Vim's manual? I could not find it by Google.

Comment: :on! actually closes other windows, not buffers.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Buffers are very different animals from windows.

Comment: Yepp, buffers are left open. Try the :%bd from the answer below, that worked for me!

Answer (score 12):

`:on` does NOT close any buffers.

It only closes the other windows.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but the following may give a desired outcome. It:

- makes the current tab the only open tab (`:tabo`)
- makes the window in the tab the only open window (`:only`)
- displays the first buffer in the open window (`1 b`)
- deletes buffers numbered 2 to 2000 (`2,2000bd`)

  `:tabo | :only | 1 b | 2,2000 bd`

Should you have more than 2000 buffers open, adjust accordingly.

It you simply want to delete all buffers, `1,2000bd` should do the job, but note that new, empty buffers will be created for all open tabs and windows.

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know you could pipe commands together in the vim command mode. +1 for that.

Comment: It's not really a "pipe" in this instance. The "bar" operator just lets you execute multiple commands in a single line in Vim. [doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:\bar)

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't save the buffers though. Maybe :wqall! :xall! is a little better.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to get VIM completely stuck you should still be able to kill it from outside VIM.

- If you're able to suspend VIM with CTRL+Z, then you can kill it with `kill %vim`
- If you can't suspend VIM you should be able to find its pid using `ps`.  The you can kill it:

```
$ ps -f -C vim
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
nfellman 27273  7473  0 Jun24 pts/15   00:00:00 /nfs/iil/home/nfellman/vim/bin/vim a.pl
nfellman 37213  23747 0 Jun23 pts/15   00:00:00 /nfs/iil/home/nfellman/vim/bin/vim b.pl
```

So if I want to kill the VIM that's editing `a.pl` you can do:

```
kill -9 27273
```

This should work even inside screen

Answer (score -3):

`:q!`

always works for me.